# Access variable in directive from other component

Tags: angular

I have created a directive for the aside section of webpage, It loads some data by http call in to a variable, I want to access that variable in other component which is forming the main body of the page. Any Help!

Comment: Why do you want to use a directive for fetching data. Sounds like a shared service would be a better fit. For more details see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Comment: Yes it sound good and I will give it a try and see if it works for me
Thanks.